# HTML: Naming conventions for ID attributes

Tags: html, naming

Lately I've been doing a lot of front-end work. Some developers here have been naming their elements things like "divPhotoGalleryContainer" and sometimes I'll just see "galleryContainer."

Is there a good naming convention? Is adding "div" really useful?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML naming conventions for ID, class and to include element type prefix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939909/html-naming-conventions-for-id-class-and-to-include-element-type-prefix)

Answer (score 3):

The stupid thing is, Hungarian notation like `divPhotoGalleryContainer` is totally unnecessary with CSS. You can name the ID `PhotoGalleryContainer` and target it to a `<div>` element in the CSS:

```
div#PhotoGalleryContainer {
  /* rules */
}
```

Inside that rule you can usually assume certain properties like `display: block`, unless you're targeting generic divs somewhere else (kinda bad practice).

There aren't really any specific conventions for naming, just use names that are clear and simple.

Comment: The other thing, too, is what happens if divPhotoGalleryContainer is no longer a div later on? What if ulProductList becomes an ol?

Comment: You don't need to infer the type of an element with an id, because the id is unique. You might however use Hungarian notation in this imaginary example: #passwordContainer, as it is easily differentiated from #passwordLabel, and #passwordInput

Comment: @ribot Technically you could apply the ID to different elements on different pages. Having said that, public consensus 3 years since this question is to avoid over-qualified selectors entirely, and avoid ID selectors unless really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's particularly useful, but I don't think it's harmful either.  Consistency is the most important convention.

Comment: LOL, I guess someone doesn't agree, but isn't constructive enough to say why.

Answer (score 1):

The best naming convention is the one that makes sense to the developers/designers involved in the project.  Given the two examples in your question, I'd be willing to bet that the "divPhotoGalleryContainer" contains "div" because either: it's referenced in a CSS selector, or some javascript code is looking at it and it's somehow *helpful* to know what type of element the id is referring to.

The "divPhotoGalleryContainer" convention seems like an HTML-ish flavor of [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

Answer (score 1):

It is good to have a naming convention, because it will make you keep track of your elements and classes, and save you from having to read the html code to find out what element is named what. This will help you both when writing css and javascript. A good naming convention for an id should include:

- a way to differentiate closely related elements, such as #passwordContainer from #passwordLabel and #passwordInput
- structural names rather than presentational names, for example #main-content rather than #blue-square (as the color might change later). More info here: http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-2-structural-naming-convention-in-css/
- a way to differentiate similar elements, for example on a page that lists different posts that have the same type of elements, you may name them #postContainer-43 and #postContainer-95 for post number 43 and 95 respectively, and give them the class .post or .postContainer

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is that you're consistant with whatever method you use.

However, I've always found it helpful to use the hungarian type notation of "divPhotoGalleryContainer", and "txtLastName". It makes it easier to distinguish page elements from other variables, both client and server side.

Answer (score 0):

It's not harmful to add "div" in that case. 
As DisgruntledGoat said, hungarian notation can be useless with CSS (that is, unles you don't want to restrict a class to one element type), and Rob's comment is right, you may even change your elements and keep the same classes/IDs, but, it may be helpful to understand the code better, lately.

I always use hungarian notation because I'm used to it. If you're used to something, keep it, as it's easier than changing it. In enviroinments where many coders are writing the same things, unless there is a convention, you may write as you want. However, being over-descriptive is not as bad as being under-descriptive. That said, I vote for comprehensive names for everything including variables, functions, classes, IDs, XML elements, etc. If it gets hard to read, use more/better placed spaces/lines. If it adds more than wanted to the file size, minify it.